# com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'DATE' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

My entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "emp", name = "person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 */

@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false,length = 50)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Id
@XmlElement
String id;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "ADDRESS", length = 50)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlElement
String address;
/**
 */

@Column(name = "EMAIL", length = 50)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlElement
String email;



@Column(name = "DATE")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlElement
DateTime date;
/**
 */

/*getters and setters */
```

}

I'm using joda time for my date. When I persist, it throws this exception:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'DATE' at row 1

My Date field contain this value : 2015-09-02T16:24:05.226+04:00

Below is the code where it persist in db:

```
    public Person save(Person person) {

    Person currentPerson = entityManager.find(Person.class,
            person.getId());
    if (currentPerson != null) {
        entityManager.detach(currentPerson);
        person =entityManager.merge(person);
    } else {
        entityManager.persist(person);
    }
    return person;
}
```

I am using hibernate/jpa and mysql. My database is created base on my entity class. my date is of type datetime in my entity class, but in database it is of type tinyblob.

Comment: Did you apply the [`Joda-Time-Hibernate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-hibernate/userguide.html) mapping?

Comment: What do you mean? Whatever i posted above thats all i've done

Comment: Hibernate does not understand Joda, so it likely just falls back to sending the data as a string, and MySQL doesn't understand/support the string value.

Comment: So how should i do this mapping?

Comment: @Andreas which link?!

Comment: The link in my first comment.

Comment: @Andreas ok I will try this.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that'll help anyway. I didn't notice that your column type was `tinyblob`. That's just messed up!

Comment: So you mean the hibernate mapping would not work also?!

Comment: The mapping will work for mapping a Joda `DateTime` to a JDBC compatible `Timestamp` column, such as the MySQL `DATETIME`.

Comment: But it's not me who put the field date tinyblob. It's autogenerate by hibernate. I think i miss this mapping. May be it would hv created it with another datatype such as timestamp or sth else

Comment: Just saw your last comment on *Thibaut*'s answer: Your database was created by hibernate. Once you make the `Joda-Time-Hibernate` mapping, I *believe* hibernate will create the database using `DATETIME`.

Comment: Yes i think we are on the same line. So let me try this

Comment: @Andreas I don't exactly have an hbm.xml. where should I place the property type?

Comment: Well, create one, or use the annotations instead.

Comment: Am getting this exception : Unable to load Class [org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime]

Comment: Did you add the .jar file?

Comment: yes of course:
 <dependency>
   <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
   <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I have a file hibernate.properties. Can i add it like this "hibernate.org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime=dateTime" ?

Comment: Sorry, let me be more specific: Did you add the 
Joda-Time-Hibernate jar file?

Comment: this one I don't think so. 
<dependency>
 <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
 <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
 <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
this one?

Comment: ok now it's good. But am having another issue. Actually I have an android application with joda time and my server ( the one above) using jodatime. So my android device will sync with my server via webservice. When I add this annotation @type.. my android device cannot sync. it throws a webservice error. Without this annotation, My android device can sync , but then I will have this issue Data truncation. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: @Andreas I'm getting this error when I persist joda time in mysql:
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeSet

Comment: Probably version conflict: "Please note that version 1.4 is for Hibernate 3.6 and not Hibernate 4.0. The [usertype project](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/) handles Hibernate 4.0." ---  I don't use hibernate, so can't help any further. Google "hibernate joda" and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't use miliseconds with Datetime:
[mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

Comment: What do you suggest then? I need to store date and time(hours n minutes) am not interested in milliseconds

Comment: Why do you use datetime in your class and tinyblob in your database. Did you try to replace tinyblob by datetime?

Comment: It's not me who put tinyblob in db. My database is created base on my entity class by hibernate. So it's hibernate who interpret datetime to tinyblob in db

Answer (score 1):

Use `Datetime` instead of `Date` in your SQL Code when creating a new table.